# Seaborn Distplot with Density on y-axis

Tags: python, statistics, seaborn

I have looked for solutions already but could not find one that worked for my problem. I am trying to plot a histogram with a density function showing the density on the y-axis. `meanopa` are average logreturns of the S&P500.
What I do not understand is the following.

> norm_hist : bool, optional
>       If True, the histogram height shows a density rather than a count.
>       This is implied if a KDE or fitted density is plotted.

Since kde=True in my case, I am wondering why there is the number of observations on the y-axis.

```
sns.distplot(meanopa, hist=True, kde=True, bins=20, color = 'darkblue',
             hist_kws={'edgecolor':'black'}, kde_kws={'linewidth': 4})
```

Thanks in advance and again I would appreciate any sort of support.

Cheers!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Although I cannot access to your data, for a similar kind of dataframe your code works well for me. Could you post which `seaborn` version are you using? Cheers.

Comment: @lrnzcig I am using version 0.9.0. And thanks for editing the post! Looks much better now!

Comment: Also using version 0.9.0, weird... must be something related to your data, and anyhow it's difficult to help you without a reproducible problem. Could you share at least part of you data? Cheers.

Comment: @lrnzcig is the data above sufficient? Cheers!

Comment: Hey.... Ok at least to get an idea of what kind of numbers you have... when I get some time during the day I'll try to reproduce. However, for future posts, please take into account (1) it's better to not use photos (2) at the end the target is to build [a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex). That way it is easier to help you (and as a consequence you are more likely to get a good answer). Have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is ok. The y-axis is not showing the values of the histogram, but for the probability density (actually the kernel density estimate). Since your numbers are very small, the x-axis has also a very narrow interval... actually from your plot if you build a square of 0.002 x 500 to approximate the total area under the curve, the result of the full probability density is around 1, as expected.

As a note, this is a reproducible version of your problem, you can play with the rescaling (`min_rescale` and `max_rescale` values) if you want to see how the shape of the probability density changes.

```
random.seed(2)
min_rescale = -0.001
max_rescale = 0.001
close2 = [min_rescale + random.random() * (max_rescale - min_rescale) for x in range(100)] 
sns.distplot(close2, hist=True, kde=True, bins=5, color = 'darkblue',
             hist_kws={'edgecolor':'black'}, kde_kws={'linewidth': 4})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case you are not interested in the probability density function but in the **probabilities/frequencies of each bin** which is given by the count of samples in the bin divided by the total number of samples, you can use the `'weights'` attribute of the `hist_kws` parameter. Applying this to the example code of [lrnzcig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3519000/lrnzcig),

```
random.seed(2)
min_rescale = -0.001
max_rescale = 0.001
close2 = [min_rescale + random.random() * (max_rescale - min_rescale) for x in range(100)] 
sns.distplot(close2, hist=True, kde=False, bins=5, color = 'darkblue',
         hist_kws={'edgecolor':'black', 'weights': np.ones(len(close2))/len(close2)})
```

results in the following plot:
[probabilities of Histogram bins using seaborn's distplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifU5H.png)

Note that the result is **no probability density function**, instead the **weights of the bins sum up to 1** independent from the argument values of the bins.
However, this makes no sense when you are performing kde.